# Proving $\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}\Re{(\cosh z}) = \cosh(\Re z)\cdot \cos(\Im z)$

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

I want to show $\Re{(\cosh z)}) = \cosh(\Re z)\cdot \cos(\Im z)$.

I did the following:

\begin{align*} \cosh(\Re z)\cdot \cos(\Im z) &= \frac {1}{2}(e^{\Re z}+e^{-\Re z})\cdot \frac {1}{2}(e^{i\Im z}+e^{-i\Im z}) \\& = \frac {1}{4}(e^{\Re z}+e^{-\Re z})\cdot (e^{i\Im z}+e^{-i\Im z}) \\
&= \frac {1}{4}(e^{\Re z}+e^{-\Re z}) \cdot 2\\
& = \frac {1}{2}(e^{\Re z}+e^{-\Re z}) \\
&= \frac {1}{2}\Re(e^z+e^{-z}) \\
&= \Re(\cosh z)
\end{align*}

Using: $\cosh(x) = \frac {1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})$ and $\cos(x) = \frac {1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$.

I would be very glad if someone could tell me if this is correct!

Comment: Delete the first equality for sure. Now as written, it looks like you assume the result and finagle around a bit. That's not what you've done.

Comment: @AndresMejia Is this better?

Comment: yeah, for sure. I edited the formatting a bit for readability. I hope you find that okay.

Comment: @AndresMejia Sure, thanks! Better formatting is always welcome.

Comment: I don't see how you got the third equality.

Comment: @AndresMejia Well, I used $(e^{iIm(z)}+e^{-iIm(z)}) = 2$ when $z >0$. Maybe this is wrong, though.

Comment: Why would $e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2$ for $x \in \mathbb R_{>0}$? Note also that $Re(e^{ix}) \neq e^{Re(ix)}$ for $x \in \mathbb R$. This can be seen, for example because there are $x$ with $Re(x)>1$. You seem to use this in your fifth equality.

Comment: @AndresMejia Well, $e^{iIm(z)}+e^{-iIm(z)} = 2cos(Im(z))$. And if you plot both actually, you can observe we have $2$. That's why I thought this is true, but I'm not sure about the correctness, hence why I asked!

Comment: It seems easier to prove starting from $\operatorname{Re}(\cosh z)$.

Comment: @Zelda_CompSci It is not true that $(e^{i\Im z}+e^{-i\Im z})=2$.

Comment: @Zelda_CompSci How do we justify the step $ \frac {1}{2}(e^{\Re z}+e^{-\Re z}) = \frac {1}{2}\Re(e^z+e^{-z}) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, but taking the path of OP so that his /her error can be seen:
$$ \cosh\left[\operatorname{Re}(z)\right] \cdot \cos\left[\operatorname{Im}(z)\right] = \left(\frac{e^{\operatorname{Re}(z)} + e^{-\operatorname{Re}(z)}}{2}\right) \left(\frac{e^{i\operatorname{Im}(z)} + e^{-i\operatorname{Im}(z)}}{2}\right)$$
$$ = \frac{e^{\operatorname{Re}(z) + i\operatorname{Im}(z)} + e^{\operatorname{Re}(z) - i\operatorname{Im}(z)} +  e^{-\operatorname{Re}(z) + i\operatorname{Im}(z)} + e^{-\operatorname{Re}(z) - i\operatorname{Im}(z)}}{4} $$
$$ = \frac{e^{\operatorname{Re}(z) + i\operatorname{Im}(z)} + e^{-\operatorname{Re}(z) - i\operatorname{Im}(z)} + e^{\operatorname{Re}(z) - i\operatorname{Im}(z)} +  e^{-\operatorname{Re}(z) + i\operatorname{Im}(z)} + }{4} $$
$$ = \frac{e^{Re(z) + i\operatorname{Im}(z)} + e^{-\operatorname{Re}(z) - i\operatorname{Im}(z)} + e^{\operatorname{Re}(z) - i\operatorname{Im}(z)} +  e^{-[\operatorname{Re}(z) - i\operatorname{Im}(z)]}}{4} $$
$$ = \frac{e^{\operatorname{Re}(z) + i\operatorname{Im}(z)} + e^{-[\operatorname{Re}(z) + i\operatorname{Im}(z)]}}{4} + \frac{e^{\operatorname{Re}(z) - i\operatorname{Im}(z)} + e^{-[\operatorname{Re}(z) - i\operatorname{Im}(z)]}}{4} = \frac{\cosh {z}}{2} + \frac{\cosh {\overline {z}}}{2}$$
$$  = \frac{\cosh {z} + \cosh {\overline {z}}}{2} = \frac{2\operatorname{Re}{\left[\cosh{z}\right]}}{2} = \operatorname{Re}{\left[\cosh{z}\right]}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy$, then we have that

$$\cosh z=\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}2=\frac12e^xe^{iy}+\frac12e^{-x}e^{-iy}=\frac12e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)+\frac12e^{-x}(\cos y-i\sin y) $$

$$ \implies \operatorname{Re}(\cosh z)=\frac12e^x\cos y+\frac12e^{-x}\cos y=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2\cos y=\cosh x \cdot\cos y$$

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question in the body.

Comment: I should clarify that I did not downvote

Comment: @AndresMejia Yes you are right! I've just revised the derivation.

Comment: Upvoted simply because I consider this the most direct and clearest proof. It seems some of the other answers are unnecessarily obfuscated because they wanted to mirror what the OP did. We shouldn't fall into this trap - it's never a given that the OP has found the simplest solution or the clearest way to present something. This solution gives some valuable tips - in a problem like this, encode the real and imaginary parts into single letter variables for clarity. Invoke the trigonometric form early to help split the real and complex parts. All these things will make future problems easier.

Comment: @Deepak Thanks a lot for you kind appreciation! I must agree with you :P

Answer (score 1):

Using the sum of angles formulae,

$\cosh(x+iy)=\cosh(x)\cosh(iy)+\sinh(x)\sinh(iy)$

but $
\cosh(iy)=\cos(y)$ and $\sinh(iy)=i\sin(y)$

so:   $\cosh(x+iy)=\cosh(x)\cos(y) + i \sinh(x)\sin(y)$

QED